# Creating AngularJS custom filter that actually Sort

Tags: angularjs

I know that in angularJS there is some built in filter: for example  `<li ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy:'name'">`

But I don't want to use it, I want to build a custom filter like above one.

and I tried below one but I am not getting how to do it.

Do you have any example like this one?

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.filter('filterByName', function () {
  return function (item) {
      // do something there
  };
});
```

Anyone know how to do it or any example like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Refer to the example below

```js
var app = angular.module('so', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.students = [{'name': 'student'}, {'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'austin'}, {'name': 'doe'}];
});

app.filter('filterByName', function () {
  return function (item) {
      return item.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="so">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="student in students | filterByName track by $index">{{student.name}}</li>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great support, You made my day